# You can see where he'd have trouble!

Tags: word-usage

In the link below, at 2:51, what does the following mean and why did Ross say "Would"?

> Ross: You can see where he'd have trouble!

This is my conclusion:
I think **WOULD** is used in a hypothetical condition. 
Can we rephrase  it this way?
"If your father didn't understand that metaphor, then you can see he would have trouble understanding you."

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh0I...o7JxLJgqC4ODfK

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Comment: @TaylorSpark because they weren't sure if they were correct and were asking for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a contraction of "he would". They are therefore equivalent.

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/he-d)